# Lobobrowser HtmlPanel in MigLayout not rendering until resize

Tags: rendering, miglayout

My MigLayout Dialog uses a HtmlPanel to display a local html file in it. However the html file is not displayed until I resize the dialog.
It seems that the HtmlPanel is not fully rendered yet as the Dialog pops up, so MigLayout does not know what to do with it. Manually specifying the width and height of the Dialog so that the html page fits in it does nothing.
My workaround as of now is to delay the popup Dialog by 500ms to ensure the htmlPanel finished navigating. On slower cpus that wont suffice though.
How can I make sure the htmlPanel has finished navigating before I try to display it in a Dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the lobobrowser before, but couldn't you build the dialog, show it with a "loading..." message, then fire the event to load the page like this:

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(goLoadPage());

Also, there appear to be events you can patch into.  http://lobobrowser.org/platform-api/org/lobobrowser/gui/ResponseAdapter.html  Maybe when that event fires, you can force a repaint.